# Hotjar clicks outside of the application

Tags: analytics, heatmaps, user-tracking

I use hotjar for my products and sometimes we have unsual behavior that is always repeated (ex: user clicking in an empty part of the screen).

Does this happens because hotjar is recording clicking for other windows?

The recordings make it seem like the user is making the same mistake over and over again in a very odd way cause it shows the clicking animation.

If it is and "outside window" click, does this affect heatmaps as well?

I couldn't find any info on google, so if it does exist, can someone share with me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically clicking in an empty part of the screen isn't the same as clicking outside of the application (for example, if the browser windows as minimized).

Your best clue is to look at the similarities in the events leading up to this action, whether it be a particular type of function or feature the user is using, or perhaps the same type of user interface element that the user is interacting with.

My guess (without more details) is that the user is confused about something and can't go back to where they think they should be before, and therefore clicking outside the current flow or interface section is how they are re-orienting themselves.

If this is also a rare event, it could be a sign of a bug that might not be triggered very often.

In any case, for any analytics driven activity, you'll need to build up the numbers to know that it is a significant event, and verify the cause of it by doing some actual user research (that will probably be qualitative).